# arrow function in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const MyComp = () => <button onClick={() => nagivate('/')}>home</button>
```

I have code above where I put arrow function inside my onClick handler. My colleague asked me to do this instead:

```
const MyComp = () => {
   const handleClick = () => nagivate('/')
   return <button onClick={handleClick}>home</button>
}
```

What is the point of it? he argue we can have performance issue. I'm confused.

Comment: Oh really!? I would also like to know what performance issue is you colleague talking about. Never heard this. Once might argue about making the code more manageable but performance !!?  :)

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are equivalent. The `handleClick` function will we redefined on every render. To improve performance use `useCallback(() => nagivate('/'), [nagivate])`. Then the function will only change if the `navigate` function changes.

Comment: in what case navigate function change? says navigate function is from react-router dom

Comment: The function will probably never change. But it is good practice to name all dependencies.

Comment: in what case you want to use useCallback for function change? it make no sense to me, if it's object or other value like big array then it make sense

Comment: If `navigate` does not change it would be better to define `const goHome = () => nagivate('/')` in module scope (without `useCallback`) and use this function as onClick handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass anonymous function as event handler it will cause function recomputation(recreation) on each rerender, thus forcing element which exposed you event to also rerender since it "thinks" that new handler is passed because of new function reference of your anonymous event handler.
If function recomputation affects your UI performance I suggest you to wrap handler in useCallback and like that you will have stable reference of you handler.
At the end I disagree with you colleague that this(one simple button) will have impact on you performance, if it does it means that your upper levels are the ones that needs optimizations. It is cleaner but in terms of performance, in this specific case, almost no difference.